# String matching between two pyspark dataframe columns

Tags: python, string, pyspark

I have a dataframe **cities**

```
country      cities
  UK        [London,London Luton, Luton]
  UK        [London,London Gatwick, Gatwick]
```

and reference dataframe **airports**:

```
city         airport            coords
London        London Luton       12.51
London        London Gatwick     100.32
```

I want to match list of values in **cities** column with **airport** column from reference df. If it matches, get the relevance airport names and co ordinates from the reference df.

Sample of the desired output of **cities df**:

```
country      cities                                airport            coords
  UK        [London,London Luton, Luton]           London Luton       12.51
  UK        [London,London Gatwick, Gatwick]       London Gatwick     100.32
```

**Explanation:**

`[London,**London Luton**, Luton]` from **cities** matches with `**London Luton**` in **airport**

I have explored some options but couldn't really get there. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains) to mark rows which contain your search string and finally filter on the rows which returns `True`

#### Data Preparation

```
d1 = {
    'cities':[
                 ['London','London Luton', 'Luton'],
                 ['London','London Gatwick', 'Gatwick']
            ],
    'country':['UK','UK']
    
    
}

d2 = {
    'country':['UK','UK'],
    'city':['London','London'],
    'airport':['London Luton','London Gatwick'],
    'coords':[12.51,100.32]
}


sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d1))
sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d2))

sparkDF1.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------+-------+
|cities                           |country|
+---------------------------------+-------+
|[London, London Luton, Luton]    |UK     |
|[London, London Gatwick, Gatwick]|UK     |
+---------------------------------+-------+

sparkDF2.show()

+-------+------+--------------+------+
|country|  city|       airport|coords|
+-------+------+--------------+------+
|     UK|London|  London Luton| 12.51|
|     UK|London|London Gatwick|100.32|
+-------+------+--------------+------+
```

#### Array Contains

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                       ,sparkDF1['country'] == sparkDF2['country']
                       ,'inner'
                    ).select(sparkDF1['*'],sparkDF2['airport'])


finalDF = finalDF.withColumn('flag',F.array_contains( F.col('cities'),F.col('airport') ) )


finalDF.filter(F.col('flag') == True).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+----+
|cities                           |country|airport       |flag|
+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+----+
|[London, London Luton, Luton]    |UK     |London Luton  |true|
|[London, London Gatwick, Gatwick]|UK     |London Gatwick|true|
+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column on the cities table with the airport name.
Then you could simply merge the two tables on the `airport` column.

Using the prep core from @Vaebhav:

```py
sparkDF1 = sparkDF1.withColumn("airport", F.col("cities")[1])

sparkDF1.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+
|cities                           |country|airport       |
+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+
|[London, London Luton, Luton]    |UK     |London Luton  |
|[London, London Gatwick, Gatwick]|UK     |London Gatwick|
+---------------------------------+-------+--------------+


finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2, on="airport", how="right")

finalDF.show(truncate=False)

+--------------+---------------------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
|airport       |cities                           |country|country|city  |coords|
+--------------+---------------------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
|London Luton  |[London, London Luton, Luton]    |UK     |UK     |London|12.51 |
|London Gatwick|[London, London Gatwick, Gatwick]|UK     |UK     |London|100.32|
+--------------+---------------------------------+-------+-------+------+------+
```